# ‘CvLoadImage’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c, opencv, compiler-errors

I try to use OpenCV C Api in my code. I have `opencv` and `opencv2` folder under `usr/include`. I can use OpenCV C++ Api. C++ code and compilation&linking commands are below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    Mat im = imread("Sobel.jpg");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile : `g++ -c main.cpp`

Linking : `g++ -o exe main.o`pkg-config --libs opencv`

Now I want to use OpenCV C-Api. My code is here :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    IplImage* pImg = CvLoadImage("Sobel.jpg");
    if(pImg == NULL)
         return -1;

    // ... big bloat to do the same operations with IplImage    

    CvShowImage("Image", pImg);
    cvWaitKey();
    CvReleaseImage(&pImg); // Do not forget to release memory.
    // end code here

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile `g++ -c main.cpp`, the compiler says that `‘CvLoadImage’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: Check your spelling, remember that C++ is case sensitive.

Comment: cvLoadImage() is what he means

Comment: @JoachimPileborg many thanks. if you write your command as an answer, I click to aceppt your answer.

Comment: please forget, that opencv's c-api ever existed. you're not allowed to use it anymore.

Comment: @berak how do I blocked to use c-api? I can compile and run upper code.

Answer (score 2):

A simple spelling mistake, the function prototype is

```
IplImage* cvLoadImage( const char* filename, int iscolor=CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR );
```